# Numbers are displayed in blue font in iphone simulator

Tags: ios, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, numbers, ios-simulator

I have customized css to overrride default css of bootstrap. But, numbers (esp. phone numbers) are being displayed in blue color when i check it using iphone 6.0 simulator.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

> Open ios simulator --> click ios simulator from menu bar --> then Reset
>   Content and Settings